# delete mutation is executed before modal is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, apollo-client

**Description**

i'm working on reactjs and apollo client project. i'm also developing deleteUser feature. delete mutation is working but without modal confirmation. i want to add modal confirm when admin click delete button. it means, delete mutation is executed after admin click on button yes inside modals.

**Problem**

When i'm clicking delete user button, mutation delete is executed first than modal is show. and when i'm click "yes" button, it'll be refetching data.

Here's the code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";

import { GET_ALL_USERS } from "../../../gql/query";
import { DELETE_USER } from "../../../gql/mutation";

import ModalEdit from "../Modals/ModalEdit";
import ModalConfirm from "../../Common/Modals/ModalConfirm";

const TableUserInfo = ({ data, variables }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = useState(false);

  const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const [deleteUser, { error, loading, refetch }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

  if (
    !data ||
    !data.getAllUsers ||
    !data.getAllUsers.rows ||
    !data.getAllUsers.rows.length
  ) {
    return <p className="text-center"> Tidak ada data tersedia </p>;
  }

  // delete user handler
  const handleDelete = (userToDelete) => {
    setIsDeleting( true );

    deleteUser({
      variables: { username: userToDelete },
      update(cache, { data }) {
        const { getAllUsers } = cache.readQuery({
          query: GET_ALL_USERS,
          variables,
        });

        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GET_ALL_USERS,
          variables,
          data: {
            getAllUsers: {
              ...getAllUsers,
              totalItems: getAllUsers.totalItems - 1,
              rows: getAllUsers.rows.filter((user) => user.username !== userToDelete)
            }
          }
        });
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      },
    });
  }

  return (
    <Table responsive>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Nama Pengguna</th>
          <th>Role Akun</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Tanggal Daftar</th>
          <th>Status Akun</th>
          <th>Pengaturan</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.getAllUsers.rows.map((user, index) => (
          <tr key={user.username}>
            <td>{index + 1}</td>
            <td>{user.full_name}</td>
            <td>{user.group_id}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.created_dtm}</td>
            <td>{user.status}</td>
            <td>
              {user.status !== "ACTIVE"
                ? [
                    <Button
                      key="Aktifkan Akun"
                      className="d-block mb-2 text-white bg-secondary w-100"
                    >
                      Aktifkan Akun
                    </Button>,
                    <Button
                      key="Ganti Role Akun"
                      className="d-block mb-2 btn-block btn-sm w-100"
                      disabled
                    >
                      Ganti Role Akun
                    </Button>,
                  ]
                : user.group_id === "admin"
                ? [
                    <Button
                      key="Ganti Role Akun"
                      variant="outline-success"
                      className="d-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
                    >
                      Ganti Role Akun
                    </Button>,
                  ]
                : [
                    <Button
                      key="Pilih Role Akun"
                      className="d-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
                    >
                      Pilih Role Akun
                    </Button>,
                  ]}
              <Button
                key="Edit"
                variant="outline-primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  setShowModal(true);
                  setUsername(user.username);
                }}
                className="d-block btn-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
              >
                Edit
              </Button>
              <Button
                key="Hapus"
                variant="outline-danger"
                onClick={() => { 
                  handleDelete(user.username)}
                }
                disabled={loading}
                className="d-block btn-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
              >
                Hapus
              </Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      {showModal ? (
        <ModalEdit
          show={handleShowModal}
          onClose={handleCloseModal}
          username={username}
        />
      ) : isDeleting ? ( <ModalConfirm 
            show={ isDeleting } 
            onHide= { () => { handleCloseModal(); setIsDeleting(false);  } } 
            handleDelete={ handleDelete } 
            userToDelete={ username } />
      ) : null}
    </Table>
  );
};

export default TableUserInfo;
```

**Question**

How to fix the error and make data user is delete when admin click "yes" in modals ?

any help will be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Is `handleDelete` supposed to delete the user (execute the mutation) or to open the modal? You're using it for both at once. Make up your mind.

Comment: so, what's the best practice sir ? i don't have any idea

Comment: You need to use two separate functions for the two steps. How you name them is up to you.

Comment: can you show the example sir ?